# Go to Definition (jump to CSS file)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using Visual Studio Code and I really love this editor for working on HTML pages. Nevertheless I am looking for a way to jump to the corresponding CSS file when I select the class or id node. Did I miss something or is this still not working?

Answer (score 14):

[CSS Navigation](https://github.com/pucelle/vscode-css-navigation/) should be good alternative, especially when you are writting Sass or Less code.

Comment: this works much better for people who write React and .jsx and use css files that get imported inside of .jsx - not exactly what I want because i want to go to definition FROM the import line and not just on the class, but hey better than nothing

Comment: CSS Navigation is better

Comment: CSS peek didn't work to me, but CSS navigation works great! Thanks (VS Code 1.51.1)

Comment: CSS Navigation should ship this in the [coming releases](https://github.com/pucelle/vscode-css-navigation/issues/21#issuecomment-783291250)

Comment: The latest version of [CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) now also implements support for React, sass, less, and more. I'd say that's the recommended option once again

Answer (score 13):

As @Mike said, try the [CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) extension, it does what you want nicely.

[image: demo of CSS Peek in operation.]

Comment: The latest version now also supports React, JSX, Sass, Less, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Features like this are implemented in extensions. So if the HTML support extension you have installed supports providing locations of CSS rules to Visual Studio then it will allow you to jump to that location. If not then not.

I haven't looked for HTML extensions, but it could be there are several in the VS code market place. See if if one of them supports CSS as well (which makes it likely that they also report CSS rule locations to VS code).